# What is the best way to lay out nested data in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am attempting to create a report that contains a list nested within another list to produce the following layout:

```
      User name: Bob
      User info: Interesting stuff about Bob
    Permissions: Administrator
                 SuperUser
                 User

      User name: Next user
      etc...
```

The data looks like this:

```
    UserName     Details    PermissionName

    Bob          Interes... Administrator
    Bob          Interes... SuperUser
    Bob          Interes... User
    NextUser     More stuff User
```

In my example I am trying to display the user details using a list and then to display the permissions using a second list embedded within the first list. I decided to do this because there are a variable number of permissions that can be assigned to a user. However this approach doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way or am I just missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a table control and group your data on "UserName" with the detail grouped on "Permission".

Comment: Thanks Mozy your approach works fine. In fact experimenting further the grouping turned out to be the essential part. I tried adding a grouping to the parent list view in my example and it also worked.

Answer (score 2):

how about using a sub report for the 2nd set?

Comment: Thanks. This would work fine but I have a lot of different data to display using this layout on one report and I don't want to have to create lots of reports.